# How can we use script to compare two fields in the same document

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am facing an issue that you have not discussed in your lecture. How can I get results by comparing two fields. I am below providing you a sample data. I only need those records where an order's **returnValue** is not equal to its **payments.paymentValue**.

Below is the sample record structure:

```
{
        "_index" : "return-202202",
        "_type" : "return",
        "_id" : "return-202202",
        "_source" : {
          "country" : "US",
          "referenceInvoiceNumber" : null,
          "returnValue" : 25.2,
          "payBonus" : true,
          "payments" : [
            {
              "paymentValue" : 25.2,
              "paymentTransactions" : [
                {
                  "transactionType" : "REFUND",
                  "transactionIssuerCode" : null,
                  "transactionCurrency" : "USD",
                  "transactionStatus" : "SUCCESS",
                  "transactionAmount" : 55.2,
                  "transactionDate" : "2022-02-01T00:02:50Z",
                  "transactionId" : "011111XXXXX-REFUND"
                }
              ],
 
              "paymentId" : "011111XXXXXX",
              "paymentCreationDate" : "2022-01-16T02:37:37Z",
              "paymentStatus" : "PAID",
              "paymentType" : "CREDITCARD"
            }
          ],
          "returnCustomerName" : "XXXX EEEEE",
          "invoiceNumber" : "33323615555",
          "returnDateTime" : "2022-01-30T21:46:22Z",
          "eventId" : "dd424508-eeeee-4c61-a366-06beeee5b4a6",
          "eventType" : "RETURN_REFUND_ISSUED"
        }
}
```

The query that I come up with but not working at all is given below:

```
{
  "size":1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "eventType": {
              "query": "RETURN_REFUND_ISSUED"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": 1673678805986,
              "lte": 1678862805986,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "doc['returnValue'].value != doc['payments.paymentValue'].value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the mapping type of the `payments` field? Is it `nested` by any chance?

Comment: no. It is an Array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

After more research, hit-and-tries, I found a fix, and my query is working now. But people can still suggest a better solution if it exists.

```
"filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "painless",
              "source": "Math.round(doc['returnValue'].value * 100) / 100 != Math.round(doc['payments.paymentValue'].values.sum() * 100) / 100"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```